# show two dropdown selection in same form using php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

please i need help for my problem which is view two dropdown selection in the same form ...i trying in my code to show them all but it show only one dropdown select and when i click on the first dropdown select after click it it will show the second dropdown select  ...is there any solution for this problem ??
`

`````
> here is my code
here is my code:
<head>
<script>
function showselect() {
$("#ff").submit();
}
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#f").hide();

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST" name="ff" id="ff">
<select id="" name="appname" class="s" >
<option value="" selected="true" disabled="disabled">date of appointment</option>
<?php
$query1 ="SELECT * FROM appo where p>0";
$result1 = $conn->query($query1);
if($result1->num_rows> 0){
while($option=$result1->fetch_assoc()){
$wed =$option['wed'];
$p =$option['p'];
?>
<option value="<?php echo $p; ?>"  ><?php echo $wed; ?> </option>
<?php
}}
if($_POST['appname']){
$appname=$_POST['appname'];
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#f").show();
});
</script>
<?php
$sqh="SELECT * FROM form where i ='$appname'";
?>
</select>
<?php
$sqh2="SELECT * FROM appo where p ='$appname'";
$querys = $conn->query($sqh2);
while($row3=mysqli_fetch_array($querys,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
$p=$row3['p'];
$wed=$row3['wed'];?>
<div class="ff" id="f">date of appointment   :<?php echo $wed;?></div>
<?php
}
?>
<center>
<table class="table1" >
<?php 
echo"<tr>";
?>
<th style="width:30px;">checking</th><th style="width:250px;">full name of employee</th><th style="width:200px;">careertitle</th><th style="width:250px;">work place</th>
<th style="width:200px;">type of require</th>
<th style="width:250px;">date of require</th>
<?php
echo"</tr>";
$query = $conn->query($sqh);
while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
$id=$row2['id'];
$full=$row2['fullname'];
$career=$row2['careertitle'];
$work=$row2['workplace'];
$statee=$row2['statee'];
$datee=$row2['datee'];
echo"<tr>";
?><td ><input type="checkbox" name="chck[]" id="check" onclick="showbutton()" value=<?php echo $id ?>/> </td>
<?php
echo"<td>$full</td>";
echo"<td>$career</td>";
echo"<td>$work</td>";
echo"<td>$datee</td>";
$sql4="SELECT * FROM cstatee where empid='$statee'";
$query4=mysqli_query($conn,$sql4); 
while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($query4,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
$sname=$row1['sname'];
echo"<td>$sname</td>";
}
echo"</tr>";
}
}?>
</table>


<!--///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->  

<select id="" name="tname" class="s">
<option value="" selected="true" disabled="disabled">the full requirement</option>
<?php 
$query ="SELECT * FROM cstatee";
$result = $conn->query($query);
if($result->num_rows> 0){
while($option=$result->fetch_assoc()){
$options =$option['sname'];
$id =$option['empid'];
?>
<option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"  ><?php echo $options; ?> </option>
<?php
}}
if($_POST['tname']){
$tname=$_POST['tname'];
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#f").show();
});
</script>
<?php
$sqh="SELECT * FROM form where statee ='$tname'";
?>
</select>
<?php
$sqh2="SELECT * FROM cstatee where empid ='$tname'";
$querys = $conn->query($sqh2);
while($row3=mysqli_fetch_array($querys,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
$empid=$row3['empid'];
$sname=$row3['sname'];?>
<div class="ff" id="f">type of require :<?php echo $sname;?></div>
<?php
}
?>
<center>
<table class="table1" >
<?php 
echo"<tr>";
?>
<th style="width:30px;">checking </th><th style="width:250px;">full name of employee</th><th style="width:200px;">careertitle</th><th style="width:250px;">work place</th>
<th style="width:250px;">date of require</th>
<?php
echo"</tr>";
$query = $conn->query($sqh);
while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
$id=$row2['id'];
$full=$row2['fullname'];
$career=$row2['careertitle'];
$work=$row2['workplace'];
$datee=$row2['datee'];
echo"<tr>";
?><td ><input type="checkbox" name="chck[]" id="check" onclick="showbutton()" value=<?php echo $id ?>/> </td>
<?php
echo"<td>$full</td>";
echo"<td>$career</td>";
echo"<td>$work</td>";
echo"<td>$datee</td>";
echo"</tr>";
}
?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#update").slideToggle(1000);
});
</script>
</table>
<?php
}

?>



<input type="submit" name="update" id="update" value="editing" onClick="fup()"   style="width:250px;height:80px;color:black;
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,rgb(211, 106, 134),#3cb59d);background-repeat: no-repeat;margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px;">

<?php
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
if(isset($_POST['chck'])){
foreach($_POST['chck'] AS $selected){
$_SESSION['id']=$selected;?>
<script>
window.location.href="update.php";
</script>
<?php
}
}    
}
?>
</form>
</body>````
`````

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure you have included the jQuery library in your code. If not, add the following script tag before your existing script tags in the head section:

   ```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. Add unique IDs to your dropdowns to distinguish them. Currently, you have empty IDs for both dropdowns. Modify your code to provide unique IDs for each dropdown:

   ```
   <select id="tname1" name="tname1" class="s">
   ```
3. Lastly, you are using the same ID ("check") for multiple checkboxes. IDs should be unique within the HTML document. If you need to apply the same functionality to multiple checkboxes, consider using a class instead.